# Excel VBA - when looping through files in a directory, how to skip to next file onError

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looping through the files in a directory, where I need to open each file, do some manipulations and then close it.

From time to time the Workbooks.Open fails with an error, and I simply want to display a MsgBox and then continue to the next file in the directory loop. But since the Error block is outside the loop, I can't just call 'Loop'... so how do I do this ?

The test below immediately triggers an error that I can't call "Loop" without a "For"...

```
Sub test()
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim filename As String

    folderPath = 'C:\myDirectory'
    filename = Dir(folderPath & "*.xlsx")

    Do While filename <> ""

        On Error GoTo OpenFailedError
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & filename)
        On Error GoTo 0

        filename = Dir
    Loop

Exit Sub

OpenFailedError:
    MsgBox ("Unable to open file " & filenameString)
    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is untested, but better, I'm sure.

Note that you have a couple of undeclared variables: `wb` and `filenameString`. I strongly recommend using `Option Explicit` at the top of each module to avoid undeclared or misnamed variables. In this case, it looks like `filenameString` was supposed to be `FileName`. Note also that I put some capitals in the variable names. This helps you notice when you mistype a name (using lower-case letters) as it will fail to resolve to upper-case.

At any rate, I'd move the error-check inside the main loop:

```
Sub test()
Dim FolderPath As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook

FolderPath = "C:\myDirectory\"
FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xlsx")

Do While FileName <> ""
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FileName)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox ("Unable to open file " & FileName)
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    FileName = Dir
Loop

End Sub
```

EDIT: Per Sid's suggestion, added a "\" to the end of `FolderPath`.

Comment: Might be an idea to add in an `Else` clause just to make it completely obvious

Comment: + 1. Nicely done. One thing though... `FolderPath = "C:\myDirectory"` Missing a `"\"` :)

Answer (score 2):

I am wondering why would `Set wb = Workbooks.Open()` fail at all if you are trying to open an xlsx file? unless the file is corrupted?

The main reason why I see the code failing is because it is missing a `"\"` in the file path

```
folderPath = "C:\myDirectory"
filename = Dir(folderPath & "*.xlsx")
```

Change the above to

```
FolderPath = "C:\myDirectory"

If Right(FolderPath, 1) <> "\" Then FolderPath = FolderPath & "\"

FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xlsx")
```

And if you missed the `"\"` by mistake in your question, then follow what Doug suggested (with a slight edit)

I added two lines to Doug's code

```
If Right(FolderPath, 1) <> "\" Then FolderPath = FolderPath & "\"
```

and

```
Err.Clear
```

Here is the edited code.

```
Sub test()
    Dim FolderPath As String, FileName As String
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook

    FolderPath = "C:\myDirectory"

    If Right(FolderPath, 1) <> "\" Then FolderPath = FolderPath & "\"

    FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xlsx")

    Do While FileName <> ""
        On Error Resume Next
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FileName)
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            MsgBox ("Unable to open file " & FileName)
            Err.Clear
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
        FileName = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: the open is failing because the filenames sometimes contain accents (I'm in France) and this seems to confuse the Dir Loop sometimes...

Comment: eg. "Cécile Thomas" (among others) threw an "unable to locate file" error this last time, but file names with accents don't always throw errors...

Comment: Also throwing errors when files are .xlsx conversions of .ods

Comment: I am glad you have got your answer but I am very curious and I would like to learn how vba interprets accented characters in excel file name and what is the best way to open such file using VBA without getting any errors :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout, do you really need the `Err.Clear` line, as the `On Error GoTo 0` automatically clears the error?  Just asking, for learning purposes.

Comment: @DaveU: Yes `On Error GoTo 0` clears the error but it's a good practice to explicitly clear it. Reason being, you could have extra code in the If-Endif construct with some other error handling and in such a case you might get unexpected results since `On Error GoTo 0` is after the endif. :)

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is to use on error resume next but that wont let you handle errors, it will just skip it.

to handle errors you can use on error go to . here are some examples of how to use both.

[On Error](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm)

Comment: not sure who unvoted this but this is the answer. hope it helps!

Comment: This answer is incorrect. In VBA we are often forced to use On Error to handle things like this. -1. Also, instead of posting a link, please apply the material in that link to an answer here.

Comment: im saying ON ERROR RESUME NEXT. to handle its easier with a tag, and then use in error go to.

Comment: @bto.rdz - dunno, they are both as horrible as each other to me ;-). That said, `On Error Resume Next` doesn't prevent you from handling errors - it just means you have to keep on checking `Err.Number`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd either do what Doug Glancy suggests or define a helper function:

```
Function TryOpenWorkbook(ByVal FileName As String, ByRef WBook As Workbook) As Boolean
On Error Goto Except
  Set WBook = Workbooks.Open(FileName)
  TryOpenWorkbook = True
  Exit Function
Except:
  MsgBox Err.Description, vbWarning, "Error " & Err.Number
End Function

Sub Test()
  Dim folderPath As String
  Dim filename As String
  Dim wb As Workbook

  folderPath = 'C:\myDirectory'
  filename = Dir(folderPath & "*.xlsx")

  Do While filename <> ""
    If TryOpenWorkbook(folderPath & filename, wb) Then
      ' do stuff...
    End If
    filename = Dir
  Loop
End Sub
```